# Want to develop website like Facebook - handles millions of requests - high performance

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I want to develop a website like Facebook in Java which handles millions of requests at the same time. Please suggest me which Java framework, web server or application server and database are reliable to develop a secure and high performance website like Facebook.

Comment: tell me if you have millions of request on a site like facebook

Comment: Check some of the question in meta so. it describes how they have handled this thing for SO.

Comment: Why stop at millions? Aim higher man!

Comment: I want a pony! No ... no ... a Narwhal!

Comment: What is your budget?  You are going to need some serious hardware and a team of developers?  BTW: AFAIK, Facebook doesn't use Java, it uses PHP which may not be as performant or secure but is perhaps more flexible to change.

Comment: @Brian Roach, Then you can call yourself Hazelelponi though its a girls name, and rarely used for some reason. ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazelelponi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JBoss EAP](http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/application/) aims to provide these qualities.

If you go this (Java standards) way, you'll use the Java EE stack - EJB 3, JPA, JMS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Build your app first, make it scale later.

Comment: Hmm, I wouln't say so. Scaling is one of things which must be considered even *before* application *design* - when choosing the technologies.

Comment: agreed with Ondra. if you are aiming for big numbers, then desing for big numbers. you dont want to have your service/product down for several days because it was succesful.