# Increasing speed of rest api

Tags: java, performance, rest, jersey

I have a set of APIs written in **JERSEY**, and all working fine. 
Now lets say the API is to be consumed by millions of people with test case of 10 million requests on an URI per second.

So how can I speed up the overall performance and reduce the latency of my API.
Consider below code as example for most of my APIs

```
    @GET
    @Path("/path/{id}")
    public Response getUserData(@PathParam("id")final long id){
        chechAuthencticationAndAuthorization();
        Userdetails userDetails = dbDao.getUserDetailsFromId(id);
        return Response.status(200).entity(userDetails).build();
    }
```

how can I speed up database read and writes and over all reponse time to scale up to millions of request per second.

Comment: How you speed up these operations depends on what you are doing, however it is likely you will need multiple servers to support this many REST requests per second.  I would see how many a single server can handle, and develop a solution so that as you have N times as many servers you get N times the throughput.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered

here [Want to develop website like Facebook - handles millions of requests - high performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665328/want-to-develop-website-like-facebook-handles-millions-of-requests-high-perf)

and [What needs to be done to develop highly scalable web application in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709790/what-needs-to-be-done-to-develop-highly-scalable-web-application-in-java/7710038#7710038)

As the answers above point out you could use a Java EE application server such as JBoss to use RolesAllowed and SecurityDomain annotations. Or you could use a ServletFilter, either way it is a good idea to separate the authentication and authorization.

Again as the posts above point out the techniques for accessing the database, caching, database technology (SQL, NoSQL, etc) and also the Java persistence library (JDBC, Hibernate, MongoDriver, etc) can have a huge impact on performance.